# Sort a list of numbers into range

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I just get started with python, here is a list of int numbers:
price = [1,3,11,47,130]
and I would like the output, price_range be like:
price_range = ["0-1","1-5","10-20".....]

I know I could use if statement to iterate through the list, I tried

```
for in range(len(price)):
    if price[i] <= 1:
    price[i] == "0-1"
    elif price[i].....
    price[i] == "..."
    else:
    price[i] == ...
```

But it does not work properly, is there anything I did wrong?

Update:

sample example:

input: price = [0.5,4,8,12,25]

if price <=1 , price_range = "0-1"

if price >1 && price <=5, price_range = "1-5"

if price >5 && price <=10, price_range = "5-10"

if price >10 && price <=20, price_range = "10-20"

if price >20 && price <=30, price_range = "20-30"

output: price_range = ["0-1""1-5","5-10","10-20","20-30"]

Comment: can you post sample example with expeced output

Comment: Your indentations are off. Are you getting an error or did your code get pasted incorrectly?

Comment: And what is the pattern for the ranges? Some (0-1) has length 1, and others 4 (1-5), 5 (5-10), 10 (10-20), etc. What if a number is 1? Does it belong to 0-1 or 1-5?

Comment: It is not a joke, I just get started, I would like to sort a list of numbers into certain range, but I could not figure out what I did wrong

Comment: I update how I would like to sort my price into what range

Comment: Format the code. Use `price_range.append()` after declaring it as a list.

Answer (score -1):

There:

```
price = [1, 3, 11, 47, 130]

new_price = []
for i in price:
    if i <= 1:
        new_price.append('0-1')
    elif i <= 5:
        new_price.append('1-5')
```

you get the idea what to do with the rest

Comment: I believe , because it doesn't answer the question. `elif i <= 5:` will also cover the range `elif i <= 1`, which doesn't meet the answer.

Comment: it won't, because the code returns the first condition met; `i = 1` would satisfy the first condition, `if i <= 1` and will not get into the next condition `i <= 5`